# My code for this newton's cradle isn't working. How do I fix this?

Tags: java, processing

```java
PVector start1;
PVector end1;
PVector start2;
PVector end2;
float e = 0; //angle
float l = 350; //length
float add = 0.05;//add(to angle)
float e2 = 0;//other angle
float add2 = 0; //add to second angle

void setup() { //setup the canvas

    size(1600, 1000);
    smooth();
    strokeWeight(10);
    start1=new PVector(950,300);
    end1=new PVector();
    start2=new PVector(650,300);
    end2=new PVector();
}

void draw() {
    background(0);

    stroke(57,255,20);
    fill(57,255,20);
    ellipse(850,650,100,100);
    ellipse(750,650,100,100);
    line(750,300,750,600);
    line(850,300,850,600);

    end1.x=start1.x+l*sin(e);
    end1.y=start1.y+l*cos(e);
    end2.x=start2.x+l*sin(e2);
    end2.y=start2.y+l*cos(e2);

    ellipse(end1.x,end1.y,100,100);
    ellipse(end2.x,end2.y,100,100);
    line(start1.x,start1.y,end1.x,end1.y);
    line(start2.x,start2.y,end2.x,end2.y);

    e+=add;
    e2-=add2;
    if(e<0){
        add=0;
        add2=0.05;
    }

    if(e>1){
        add*=-1;
    }
    if(e2<-1){
    }
}
```

I know that the problem is within the last few lines but I don't know how to get around the problem. The problem is that each time `e2` gets to negative, specifically less than `-1`, the code says that now `add2` must multiply by `-1` to go the other way. But, as soon as it is more than -1, the code is also telling it that when e is less than 0(which it is), `add2=0.05`. So what's happening is that it is fluctuating between `>-1` and `<-1`. How do I get around this problem?
P.S. This explanation is only what I think the problem is but it could be completely different.

Comment: Please explain exactly what this code is supposed to do/produce, and what it actually produces/does. "The code is telling it" is a strange phrase. "It is fluctuating" - what is fluctuating? etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add integral state variables `actPendle`, which indicate the moving pendle. `add` and `add2` have to be initialized by 0.05:

```java
int actPendle = 1;
float add = 0.05;//add(to angle)
float add2 = 0.05; //add to second angle
float e = 0; //angle
float e2 = 0;//other angle
```

If `actPendle == 1`, then move the 1st pendle. If it has finished its move, the switch to the other pendle. Do the same for the 2nd pendle:

```java
void draw() {

    // [...]

    if (actPendle == 1) {

        e += add;
        if(e > 1){
            add *= -1;
        } else if (e < 0) {
            add *= -1;
            actPendle = 2;
        }
    }

    if (actPendle == 2) {

        e2 -= add2;
        if(e2 < -1){
            add2 *= -1;
        } else if (e2 > 0) {
            add2 *= -1;
            actPendle = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]